# Does the terms 'LP primal' and 'LP dual' usually refer to any primal/dual, or just the optimal primal/dual pair

Tags: optimization

As the title says, I'm wondering whether the terms *LP primal* and *LP dual* usually refers to any primal/dual pair of an LP (feasible or not), or just the optimal primal/dual pair.

The reason that I'm asking is that I found the following question (without context) in a review sheet: *If an LP primal is infeasible, what can you say about its LP dual?*

Comment: It refers to the primal and dual pair of *models*.

Answer (score 0):

If the primal problem is infeasible, then the dual problem is infeasible or unbounded.

The different cases can be summarized in a table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\texttt{primal/dual}& \texttt{infeasible} & \texttt{optimal} & \texttt{unbounded} \\ \hline
 \texttt{infeasible} & \color{blue}{\checkmark} & \color{red}{\times} & \color{blue}{\checkmark} \\ \hline
 \texttt{optimal} & \color{red}{\times}  & \color{blue}{\checkmark} & \color{red}{\times}  \\ \hline
 \texttt{unbounded} & \color{blue}{\checkmark} & \color{red}{\times}  & \color{red}{\times} \\ \hline
\end{array}